# When $\left(W_1^{\perp}+W_2^{\perp}\right)^{\perp}=W_1+W_2$ is true?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to figure out a theorem about $\left(W_1^{\perp}+W_2^{\perp}\right)^{\perp}=W_1+W_2$. I know that $(W^{\perp})^{\perp}=W$ and I also know that $W_1^\perp + W_2^\perp = (W_1 \cap W_2 )^\perp$.  But what condition do we need to have so $\left(W_1^{\perp}+W_2^{\perp}\right)^{\perp}=W_1+W_2$ is true?

Answer (score 1):

With the mentioned rules we get $W_1\cap W_2=W_1+W_2$ and therefore the equivalent condition $W_1=W_2$.